# How to split a list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm pretty new to prolog and I'm trying to do some exercises.

I need to write a predicate where if I type:

```
split([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k],3,L1,L2).
```

I should get L1 = [a,b,c] and L2 = [d,e,f,g,h,i,k].
 I should not use any predefined predicates and I need not use anything fancy or wacky.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far and ask a more specific question. And can you define *fancy* or *wacky*?

Answer (score 0):

several version to split a list in prolog but according to your suggestion this predicate will be the easiest :

```
split(Xs,0,[],Xs).  
split([X|Xs],N,[X|L1],L2) :-
        N1 is N-1,
        split(Xs,N1,L1,L2).
```